# How can I redirect an echo output to STDOUT and to a variable simultaneously?

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I want to to send echo message to Standard output and simultaneously want to store that value to variable as well. Basically echo should print on standard output and that output should get store in a variable as well.

I tried following approach but it doesn't print the echo message, and just stores the "value" to variable only.

```
 variable=$($echo "value")

 Output:
```

However, the output I am looking for is:

```
 Output:value
```

Thanks

Comment: Answered [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/526904/) on unix.SE.

Comment: @DevSolar, it worked as given in example. May I have some good document on tee. Thanks

Comment: [`man tee`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tee.1.html)???

Comment: @DevSolar that tees it to the controlling tty. What if the stdout of the script is **not** the controlling tty, as when the script itself was run from a pipeline, e.g. in `./script | less`?

Comment: @DevSolar also, what if `/dev/pts/X` or `/dev/tty` is not accessible, as when run from `su`, e.g. `su some_user -c 'var=$(echo yeah | tee /dev/tty)'` => `tee: /dev/tty: No such device or address`

Comment: @Jaraws For the reasons mentioned above, use `{ var=$(echo whatever | tee /dev/fd/3) ; } 3>&1`. If you have a system without `/dev/fd/X`, you would probably need a named pipe.

Comment: @user414777: How about you direct your discussion of the question I linked *to that question*? These are two comments not trying to clarify the question (and should be comments under the corresponding answer over at unix.SE), and an attempt to answer in a comment (which should *also* not be done).

Comment: @DevSolar why? I was trying to help the OP, not direct discussions.

Comment: @user414777: Then please post an answer.

Comment: I probably will, if I don't happen upon something simpler and which also works on systems without `/dev/fd/3`. Until then, the mentioned trick should work on OP's Linux, which does have `/dev/fd/3` ;-)

Comment: @user414777: **Please do not answer in comments.**

Comment: @user414777, how is /dev/tty is different from /dev/fd/3?

Comment: As I already said, think what happens when you're piping your script to `less` or another program. It's stdout (duped to `/dev/fd/3` in my example) will NOT be `/dev/tty`.